# Business and log data separated by DB or Schema?

Tags: database, database-schema, rdbms

When building a monolith, you probably want to have log/technical data and business/operational data separated in some way. Assuming you only use one RDBMS DB instance, would you do data separation by having multiple databases in the DB instance, or one database with multiple database schemas?